# Convert List to Python dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe

I have tried below code to convert my list object to dataframe, however, I keep getting error.

Please can someone advise?

**Code:**

```
  newframe = pd.DataFrame(np.array(basket).reshape(len(basket), -1),  
                 columns = ['currency', 'weights' , 'ric'])
```

**ERROR** :

> ValueError: Shape of passed values is (1, 55), indices imply (3, 55)

**List object:**

```
<class 'list'>: [{'currency': 'EUR', 'weight': 806311901, 'ric': '_DIVISOR'},  
{'currency': 'EUR', 'weight': 89440570.0, 'ric': 'AFXG.DE'},  
{'currency': 'DKK', 'weight': 217059600.0, 'ric': 'AMBUb.CO'},  
{'currency': 'EUR', 'weight': 37692508.0, 'ric': 'ARGX.BR'},  
{'currency': 'GBp', 'weight': 1267101448.0, 'ric': 'AZN.L'},  
{'currency': 'EUR', 'weight': 932551965.0, 'ric': 'BAYGn.DE'}, 
{'currency': 'CHF', 'weight': 55400000.0, 'ric': 'BION.S'}]
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You are reshaping your array to be 1 dimensional (i.e. 1 column) whereas the dataframe specification is for 3 columns. That is why you get an error. If you post some actual data (i.e. more detail) we can have a go at correcting ti.

Comment: yes thanks for quick response - my actual data is posted in question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(list_of_dicts)
```

Comment: thanks a lot - I was under impression to reshape my list first? will give this a go